# Where do I get the MQ DLLs I need for Perl's MQClient::* and MQSeries:: modules?

Tags: perl, message-queue, ibm-mq

I need to rejig some VERY old Windows code that uses Perl to talk to MQ.  Specifically, I need to be able to install Perl's MQClient::MQSeries, MQSeries::QueueManager, MQSeries::Queue and MQSeries::Message modules.

When I fire up Strawberry Perl, go into CPAN and try to install them, I can see that there's several MQ client DLLs that are required for these Perl modules to build.  However, they're not on my system, even after downloading and installing the current MQ Client from IBM.

It used to be that downloading and installing the MQ Client from IBM gave you the option to install a whole bunch of development libraries (presumably including the bits necessary to install the above Perl libraries), but it seems that's no longer the case.  For example, there's no MQM.DLL file anywhere, which is one file that the Perl libraries seem to need to build correctly.

Suspect I've probably just not installed the correct MQ Client package to get this stuff, but have no idea where to find it (Google is no help).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MQSeries](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MQSeries/) 1.29 was released in 16 Jun 2009, so I guess you can just ask it's maintainer.

You can also ask in newsgroup news://news.software.ibm.com/ibm.software.websphere.mq , or ask IBM's support.

Answer (score 1):

where'dja get the MQ download?
maybe you might try mqseries.net - it's a hotbed of MQ activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest downloading the WMQ Client installation.  Depending on which one you want, v7.0 is [SupportPac MQC7](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71) and v7.1 is [SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71). This will get you the client libraries with which to build the Per module.  If you need the server libs, the Evaluation download of WMQ Server v7.1 [is here](http://ibm.co/WMQEval):